# CKEDITOR drop element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have problem with get element which I pasted element in ckeditor.
In ck iframe I have two boxes ex.

```
<div class="box"> content1 </div> 
<div class="box"> content2 </div>
```

Plugin looks like

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('containers', {
    requires: 'widget',
    init: function(editor) {
        editor.addFeature(editor.widgets.registered.containers);
        editor.on('paste', function(evt) {
            var contact = evt.data.dataTransfer.getData('contact');
            if (!contact) {
                return;
            }
            evt.data.dataValue = contact.html;
        });
    } });
```

Before add new html I would like to know classes of destinations element to prevent drop element to other boxes ex. without class "box".

Maybe someone have some suggest to resolve this poblem

Comment: Please clarify what you need (and what exactly is the problem). Also - a working example will be great.

Comment: Ok, eg. I have html 
<div class="box"> content1 </div> 
<div class="box"> content2 </div> 
<div class="box2"> content3 </div>

Comment: ok, and? provide a working example (open jsfiddle.net and build the example there).

Comment: Ok eg I have a html:
 

    <div class="box"> content1 </div>
    <div class="box"> content2 </div>
    <div class="box2"> content2 </div>

And drag&drop content eg.

     
    <div class="content"> title </div>

I would like to enable drop content to div.box but prevent drop to div.box2. It's my problem because on paste event I can't recognize destination element or I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Did you read my comment? Why are you keep commenting instead of create a **working** example?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/C7N7r/221/
it's quite difficult for me to correctly run it with plugin in jsfiddle maybe you have any ideas to correct this code, thanks

Comment: You are mixing between `drag & drop` and `copy & paste` and it's really hard to understand what you are looking for and what the problem is. Try to read again everything you wrote and see if you understand anything of it. Try to describe what is the problem, what you have tried, what do you expect to get and what you actually got. Regarding the jsfiddle - it's a good start. Open the developers toolbar and see that you have errors there. You should start by fixing these errors.

Comment: ok, here is what I have now https://fiddle.jshell.net/wo572b4c/2/
on left column I have editor on right sample elements
I would like to enable drop element "DIV" to div.main-container and disable drop to div.main-container2. For this I would like to get target class, in this example it is "main-container". 
sorry for my english, I hope that you understand my problem ;)

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the `paste` event you can use the `cancel` function of the `evt` variable.

To check if the dropped place and see if that element contain a specific class you should use the Ranges feature:

```
evt.editor.getSelection().getRanges()
```

Here is a combined example:

```
sc = evt.editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0].startContainer
if (!sc.getParent().hasClass('box')) {
    evt.cancel()
    return;
}
```